# Word for telling about events of a movie/book etc

Tags: single-word-requests

When someone reveals details about surprising events which will happen in a movie or book to someone who doesn't know about them, we nowadays say that's a 'spoiler.'
I'm looking for a verb for that, which is less colloquial and less awkward than 'to spoil.'
Ideally, it would be a transitive verb, so I'd like to be able to say 'He Xed Y,' where 'X' is the verb I'm looking for and 'Y' would be the thing that was revealed.

Comment: Not very succinct, but you could say *spoiled the surprise of the ending.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't a single word, but phrase **give away** works.

[TheFreeDictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/give+away) defines *give away* as:

> To reveal or make known, often accidentally.

It can be used for movies, such as the phrase "gave away the ending".  There are a lot of examples of that on [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=movie%20%22gave%20away%20the%20ending%22&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8).

Comment: I would like to add that *give away* totally is a single word. It's just spelled with a blank, is all. There's no shortage of languages/writing systems that would spell it without. (Or indeed spell *all* the words with no blanks at all.) It's just a convention. Spaces do not delimit words. Not even in English. Observe: S P A C E. How many words is that? Five, you say? Count again.

Answer (score 2):

Before *spoiler*, people would actually use the word *reveal*.

Whilst being a verb. it can also be used as a noun, as in *the big reveal*, such as with a magic show.

> *verb* make (previously unknown or secret information) known to others.
>
> *noun* (in a film or television programme) a final revelation of information that has previously been kept from the characters or viewers.

Alternatively, you could use *unveil*

> *verb* show or announce publicly for the first time.

Definitions from *Oxford Dictionary*

Both work in the context that you've described:

> He *revealed* an object
>
> He *unveiled* an object

Comment: Would you say 'to reveal' or 'to unveil' have the negative connotation that 'to spoil' has?

Comment: @JohannesBauer 'To unveil' generally has positive connotations, as it is usually used in reference to a public gathering, such as 'unveiling a new statue', which are usually crowd-pleasing events. I don't think 'to reveal' has connotations of good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

I like *[divulge](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/divulge)*:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   Make known (private or sensitive information):
>
> ODO

Answer (score 2):

*[Disclose](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disclose)* might work well in a formal context:

> verb
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>   1 Make (secret or new information) known:

Answer (score 2):

On the colloquial scale, I would rate *[leak](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/leak)* somewhere between *spoil* and *disclose*:

> verb
>
> 2.1 [WITH OBJECT] Intentionally disclose (secret information):
>
> ODO

Answer (score 1):

For me, the biggest problem with trying to use “to spoil” as a verb for “reveal” is not its colloquial nature but "the fact" (as seen by me) that spoil/spoiler still really means “ruin” in this sense and not “reveal”:

“Don’t spoil/ruin it (the movie/the ending/whatever) for me [by revealing it (the plot twists/the ending/whatever).”

Granted, the “by revealing [whatever]” can be implied, but it’s not inherent in the word “spoil,” even as it relates to movies, for one can easily spoil a movie in other ways: by talking, farting, checking a phone, etc.).

All that said in a feeble attempt to try to persuade you to reconsider the possibility of using a colloquialism, especially one that does mean “reveal” in this sense and one that could also provide some (clever?/lame?) alliteration when used with “spoil,” to wit,

“[to spill](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/spill)”: (6. Informal. to divulge, disclose, or tell: “Don't spill the secret.”).

“You spilled the surprise [ending], you spoiler!”

Comment: Totally agree: that's the reason why I was looking for something 'less awkward.'

Answer (score 0):

synopsis: providing a summary of what happens in a film or book

Comment: But _synopsis_ is one of the few nouns that hasn't been verbed yet.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth : Google actually does give me results for 'synopsisize'  ;-)

Comment: @Johannes If that is considered an acceptable word, _synopsis_ has been verbisised, not verbed.

Answer (score 0):

About 400 years ago a guy named Will said from the mouth of another guy named Kent,

*"... mar a curious tale by telling it."*